# how to add search in select form

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to be able to write in the **select** form field or insert a **search field** to find the word present in the list in order to facilitate the search and that allows me to then open the link on the requested page.
- or a datalist who can open links as in the example.

```html
<select id="1" onchange="window.open(this.value)" name="url">test[/url]
    <option value="#" selected="selected">&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;- Search -</option>
    <option value="https://www.google.com">google</option>
    <option value="https://www.libero.it/">libero</option>
    <option value="https://stackoverflow.com/">stackoverflow</option>
  </select>
```

Thank you all

Comment: You can (_should_) use jQuery plugin for it, there are some great plugins out there, for example [Select2](https://select2.org/)

Comment: You want it to auto-complete your given input and give you suggestions? If you want to do it plain without any extensions it is pretty complex, there is a example https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete

Comment: if possible yes, thank you

Comment: I wish I could write in the field and choose one of the items in the list

Comment: We use [Select2](https://select2.org/) in many projects for this functionality. As linked above by @MehdiDehghani.

Answer (score -1):

you can [download the select2 release of your choice](https://github.com/select2/select2/tags) from GitHub and copy the files from the `dist` directory into your project.

Include the compiled files in your page:

```
<link href="path/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="path/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Select2 will register itself as a jQuery function if you use any of the distribution builds, so you can call `.select2()` on any jQuery selector where you would like to initialize Select2.

```
// In your Javascript (external .js resource or <script> tag)
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.has-select2').select2();
    // "has-select2" class of your <select>
});
```

like this for your **project**:

```js
$('select[name="url"]').select2();
```

```html
<link href="https://select2.org/assets/67d8c795b134371095fa410809f5692f.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<!-- import select2 css file -->

<script src="https://select2.org/assets/db8d1316d82fbadb18dde3096cf9e671.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- import select2 js file -->

<select id="1" onchange="window.open(this.value)" name="url">test[/url]
    <option value="#" selected="selected">&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;- Search -</option>
    <option value="https://www.google.com">google</option>
    <option value="https://www.libero.it/">libero</option>
    <option value="https://stackoverflow.com/">stackoverflow</option>
</select>
```